# Do I need ApplicationConfig.java

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey

Trying to create my first simple web service in Eclipse by project name `WebServiceRestful_Server`. `DemoRest` class code:

```
package ws;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;


@Path("demo")
public class DemoRest {

    @GET
    @Path("hello")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello()
    {
        return "Hello world";

    }

}
```

According manual I found I need `ApplicationConfig` class. I did it:

```
package ws;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("rest")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        return resources;
    }
    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        //add all resources classes
        resources.add(ws.DemoRest.class);
    }
}
```

Run on server. But when I go to `http://localhost:8080/WebServiceRestful_Server/rest/demo/hello` I see only 
[image]

How to get "Hello world" there?

Do I need ApplicationConfig.java? Looks like this code is not run. I was try to place breakpoints on both functions, but nothing was happening on them, when I run in project in Debug mode.

UPD:

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>WebServiceRestful_Server</groupId>
  <artifactId>WebServiceRestful_Server</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.j2ee</groupId>
        <artifactId>j2ee</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>WebServiceRestful_Server</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Using Maven? Which dependencies do you have in the `pom.xml`? Using `web.xml`? What does it look like?

Comment: I have updated question body with web.xml and pom.xml

Comment: `<scope>provided</scope>` remove that. That is only if the container already has this artifact. Tomcat doesn't have Jersey. When you use `provided`, the artifact doesn't get deployed with the war. So none of your Jersey jars are getting deployed

Comment: @vico Besides following [peeskillet's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42700750/do-i-need-applicationconfig-java?noredirect=1#comment72549240_42700750) (that should fix the issue), you should remove the `javax.j2ee` dependency. You don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

If you can post your web.xml and pom.xml(if you are using maven), it will be much easier to figure out what goes wrong. Configuring tomcat with jersey can be hard simply because there are just too many ways to do it. Different servlet and jersey version can have different ways to be configured. Higher versions can be configured in very flexible ways, and can cause a lot of confusion.

The annotation `@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("rest")` implies that servlet 3 container(Tomcat 7 or higher) is what you are using. If I need to make a guess without looking at your web.xml, I would say make sure that your web.xml is configured to use version 3, instead of version 2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
...
</web-app>
```

You can even delete all the content inside web-app tags, jersey will scan all your files to find out your Application class and all resource classes(annotated with at least @Path or @GET etc).
If it doesn't work, two suggestions:

- If you have time, check out the latest [official document](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html) of jersey, section *4.7. Servlet-based Deployment* is what you want to read.
- If you have no time, the quickest way is to run this maven command to have a new project set up for you. This command is actually the recommended way to download jersey in the jersey's [website](https://jersey.java.net/download.html).

  mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-webapp -DarchetypeVersion=2.25.1

Reminder: after running the maven command above, change the version to be 3.0 in you web.xml

Comment: I have updated question body with web.xml and pom.xml